# What's the easiest way to encrypt word and pdf files?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, vb6

I'm building a database for recruitment purposes in visual basic which will require CVs of candidates to be stored on my employees' hard-drives since it's too slow to download them from the cloud every time they want to view.

They need to have all the CVs stored on their computers but I will limit which CVs they have access to through my database client. In order to achieve this properly I need a simple encryption method which will encrypt and decrypt the CVs which will be in various word file formats and pdf files.

I thought about encrypting the text itself, but that will be tricky I'd imagine with all the formatting in the files and possibly pictures etc. So I guess I'd have to encrypt the file itself but I'm not sure how to do that... where to begin?

Comment: I think you'll find that if you have a sane network environment, most resume-sized doc, docx, and pdf files can be downloaded about as fast as they can be decrypted, especially considering the burden of distributing them as new resumes are acquired.

Comment: Also: the biggest concern for your plan is where to store and how to secure your decryption key.

Comment: My employees work from home as we don't have a centralised office space with an intranet. These guys aren't technical though so I'm 100% confident they won't have the faintest idea where to start if they wanted to try and hack the system ;)

Comment: Even over the web, a typical resume is less than 250K, should download even over bad consumer broadband in fewer than 5 seconds. That seems a lot better than trying to distribute resume collections in bulk.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right. My experience is from loading the CVs from a link in an excel spreadsheet. It freezes the spreadsheet and takes 20+ seconds to load. But it's much faster if I download it say in a webbrowser... so yeah maybe I'm overcomplicating things.

Comment: Probably a lot of what you're waiting for is Word or Reader to open up. The data transfer doesn't take all that long.

Comment: Well in excel I have a link to the cv on the harddrive which loads in about 3 seconds but the link to the one on the site takes 20 seconds+ and freezes excel until it loads. Not sure if it's something to do with excel or what because if I just type the link in a webbrowser the cv loads in about 5 seconds

Comment: vb.net != vb6.  Which is it?

Comment: With Excel mentioned so often I'd guess neither VB6 nor VB.Net but instead VBA.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2010 / 2013, you can encrypt a word document by using these procedures: Click File Info > Protect Document > Encrypt with password.

In Word 2007,
1. Click Office button  > Save As; In Word 2010, Click File  > Save As.
2. In the Save As window, click Tools and select General Options.
3. Enter a password in the Password to open field, and click OK.

To  Encrypt PDF Documents using Acrobat X Pro

1. Open or Create the PDF document
2. Click on "Tools", then choose Protection -> Encrypt -> Encrypt with Password
3. If a dialog box appears asking for "Applying New Security Settings", click "Yes".
4. Choose "Acrobat X and later" (Recommended Option), if the recipient is using Acrobat X or Acrobat Reader X or later. Otherwise, select "Acrobat 7.0 and later" for better backwards compatibility.

   - Ensure that "Encrypt all document contents" is selected.
   - Ensure that "Require a password to open the document" is checked.
5. Type in a password in the "Document Open Password" field. Then click "OK".

Acrobat X Pro

6. Reenter the password you have chosen and click "OK". If a dialog prompts stating that the security settings will not be applied to the document until you save the document. Click "OK". Then, save the PDF document by clicking on "File" -> "Save". And verify that "(SECURED)" appears in the title bar.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not suitable for my purpose because I will be bulk uploading CVs etc. I can't change the password for every file I don't want them having access to. The client I'm developing needs to to encrypt/decrypt the file.